# Is it possible to connect a wallet to a website through a script?

Tags: wallet, solana-wallet-adapter, walletadapter, walletprovider

So I've been thinking about making a custom wallet through the command line. 2 questions came up in my mind. Is it possible to connect to a website through just the command line? Maybe through web scraping? That idea also raises another question: whether it's possible to connect to a website with a wallet that's not supported. If someone can provide an answer to these questions that would be great :D

Comment: I'm not sure about the answer to your question but to suggest an alternative that work for some use-cases: The website provides a UI to help you build, sign, and send transactions. You might just build the transaction locally and use your script to sign and send the transaction, sidestepping any need to interact with the website in the first place. As a simple example, let's say we have candy machine mint site and we would like to mint tokens from our system wallet locally. We just grab that CM ID and create a simple script to mint. No need to interact with the mint site.

Comment: Wow, I was actually right in the middle of answering this question when it was closed.. If it reopens, I'll provide a detailed answer below. The TL;DR is that while it's technically not possible in my opinion, you can use Selenium to programmatically interact with a website and your phantom wallet in a headless browser to do a lot of what I'm guessing you'd like to do.